# Valdiation From To date

Tags: winforms

I am developing Windows Form using vs2010 C#

I have 2 datetime pickers

1 is fromDatePicker and the other is ToDatePicker

I want to validate that the toDate is always after from date are the same day

eg if From:30/8/2010...To:16/8/2010

An error message is showed to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do comparisons on `DateTimes'

```
if (toDate < fromDate)
{
    MessageBox.Show("To date is before from date");
}
```

If you're not worried about the time portion then use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property:

```
if (toDate.Date < fromDate.Date)
{
    MessageBox.Show("To date is before from date");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set a minimumDate property on your toDate control to the date on the fromDate control?